# Optimal strategy for guessing subset of given size

Tags: probability, combinatorics

(inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2769357))

Let $X$ be a set of size $n$. Suppose $A\subseteq X$ is a subset of size $a$ chosen uniformly randomly. We are given $a,k$ and want to choose $B\subseteq X$ to maximise
$$
  P(|A\triangle B|\leq k)
$$
where $A\triangle B$ is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of $A$ and $B$. By symmetry this depends only on $b=|B|$.

> Given $n,a,k$, which value of $b$ maximizes $P(|A\triangle B|\leq k)$?

Comment: Surely i am missing something but does $b=0$ gives prob 1?

Comment: @Phicar If $b=0$ then $|A\triangle B|=a$. So for $a>k$ it gives probability $0$. For $a\leq k$ you are correct that $b=0$ is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(n,a,b,k)=P(|A\triangle B|\leq k)$. Note that $A\triangle B=(X\setminus A)\triangle(X\setminus B)$, so
$$
  p(n,a,b,k)=p(n,n-a,n-b,k).
$$
Therefore we may assume $0\leq a\leq n/2$. If $k\geq a$ then $b=0$ is optimal since $p(n,a,0,k)=1$. Now assume $k<a$.

Note that $|A\triangle B|$ has the same parity as $a+b$. If $a+b+k$ is odd then
$$
  |A\triangle B|\leq k\Leftrightarrow|A\triangle B|\leq k-1
    \Rightarrow|A\triangle(B\triangle\{x\})|\leq k
$$
for any $x\in X$. Thus $p(n,a,b,k)\leq p(n,a,b\pm1,k)$. Therefore the optimal value of $b$ must have the same parity as $a-k$. If $b<a-k$ then $p(n,a,b,k)=0$, so the optimal value must be at least $a-k$. Suppose $b=a-k+2l$ where $l\geq0$. Note that
$$
  |A\triangle B|\leq k\Leftrightarrow|B\setminus A|\leq l.
$$
Suppose $B\subseteq B'$ with $|B'|=b+2$. There are three possibilities:

1. $|B\setminus A|=l$ and $|B'\setminus A|=l+2$.
2. $|B\setminus A|=|B'\setminus A|=l+1$.
3. Otherwise, $|B\setminus A|\leq l\Leftrightarrow|B'\setminus A|\leq l+1$.

Note that in cases 1 and 2, $|(X\setminus B')\cap A|$ equals $a-b+l$ and $a-b+l-1$ respectively. The number of sets $A$ in cases 1 and 2 is
$$
  \binom{b}{l}\binom{n-b-2}{a-b+l}\text{ and }
  \binom{b}{l+1}\binom{n-b-2}{a-b+l-1}
$$
respectively. Thus
$$
  p(n,a,b,k)-p(n,a,b+2,k)=
  \frac{\binom{b}{l}\binom{n-b-2}{a-b+l}-
  \binom{b}{l+1}\binom{n-b-2}{a-b+l-1}}{\binom{n}{a}}.
$$
Note that $a-b+l=k-l$. If $l\geq k$, we immediately have $p(n,a,b,k)\geq p(n,a,b+2,k)$. Suppose $l<k$. Then we obtain
$$
  p(n,a,b,k)-p(n,a,b+2,k)=
  \frac{\binom{b}{l}\binom{n-b-2}{k-l-1}}{\binom{n}{a}}
  \frac{k^2-a(k+1)+l(n-2k-2)+n-1}{(l+1)(k-l)}.
$$
If $k+1=a=n/2$ then $p(n,a,b,k)=p(n,a,b+2,k)$. Otherwise $k+1<n/2$ and
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  p(n,a,b,k)&<&p(n,a,b+2,k)\\
  \Leftrightarrow l(n-2k-2)&<&a(k+1)-k^2-n+1\\
  \Leftrightarrow (l+1)(n-2k-2)&\leq&(a-k-1)(k+1)-1\\
  \Leftrightarrow (l+1)&\leq&\frac{(a-k-1)(k+1)-1}{n-2k-2}\\
  \Leftrightarrow (l+1)&\leq&\left\lfloor
    \frac{(a-k-1)(k+1)-1}{n-2k-2}\right\rfloor.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Note that the RHS is at most $k$ since $a-k-1\leq2(a-k-1)\leq n-2k-2$. Putting together all of the above, the optimal $b$ given $n,a,k$ is
$$
  b(n,a,k)=\begin{cases}
    n-b(n,n-a,k)&\text{if }a>n/2,\\
    0&\text{if }k\geq a,\\
    a-k&\text{if }k=a-1,\\
    a-k+2\left\lfloor
    \frac{(a-k-1)(k+1)-1}{n-2k-2}\right\rfloor&\text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
(when there is a tie, the above formula prefers the lower $b$ for $a\leq n/2$).